# multiple div boxes inside flex grid layout vertically

Tags: html, css

I created a div css grid layout and it looks nice, but now I am having my first trouble positioning boxes, the layour is a holy grial 3 column for desktop only. The code is the follow:

```
    .container {
display:grid;grid-template-areas:"header header header""nav main aside""footer footer footer";
    height:100%;width:100%;grid-template-columns:250px 1fr 220px;
grid-template-rows:133px 1fr 50px;grid-gap:0;}

    header{grid-area:header;display:flex;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);border-bottom:solid 1px #282828;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}

    nav{grid-area:nav;display:flex;margin:18px 18px 18px 18px;}

    main{grid-area:main;display:flex;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);border:solid 1px #282828;margin:18px 0px 18px 0px;}

    aside {grid-area:aside;display:flex;margin:18px 18px 18px 18px;}

    footer {grid-area:footer;display:flex;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);border-top:solid 1px #282828;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

The problem is: in aside I want to put 4 boxes for ADS, vertically, I tried with normal divs and it dont separate the divs vertically, they get just together horizontally. I tried creating a table inside the ASIDE like this:

```
<div class="functions">
<div class="prepare"><div class="titles">ENERGI</div></div>
<div class="prepare"><div class="boxes">2222</div></div>
</div>

<div class="functions">
<div class="prepare"><div class="titles">ENERGI</div></div>
<div class="prepare"><div class="boxes">2222</div></div>
</div>

<div class="functions">
<div class="prepare"><div class="titles">ENERGI</div></div>
<div class="prepare"><div class="boxes">2222</div></div>
</div>

<div class="functions">
<div class="prepare"><div class="titles">ENERGI</div></div>
<div class="prepare"><div class="boxes">2222</div></div>
</div>
```

For this using the follow css:

```
.functions {
display:table;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin-bottom:50;padding:0;border:0;width:100%;height:auto;}

.prepare {display:table-row;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}

.titles {display:table-cell;padding:3px 6px 3px 6px;color: #999999;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);border:solid 1px #282828;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;margin:18px 18px 18px 18px;}

.boxes {display:table-cell;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;color: #999999;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);border:solid 1px #282828;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;margin:18px 18px 18px 18px;}
```

It looks fine with 1 box only but when I try with 4 boxes they get together like in this image;

[image]

As you can see the boxes are close to each other horizontally but I need them to be separated vertically like this:

[image]

Any idea? 
Does I have to do it with table divs or can it be fixed using just single divs ? tried many things but they seems to be a diabolical pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I to understand that those 4 divs are inside the 'aside' element? Simply add this to the css for aside:

```
flex-direction: column
```

Then for guttering you can add

```
margin-bottom: 10px
```

to your "functions" class

Comment: I'm delighted to hear it! Would be nice to mark the answer as correct, or at least un upvote

Comment: One more small thing, can I use normal divs instead of table divs for the boxes ?

Comment: Yeah you can. And if you want to have the boxes change their height so that they take the whole height of the column, just add `flex: 1` to the functions class